# Getting Cors error in Laravel on some system

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cors

I hosted laravel (Laravel Framework 8.68.0) and angular application on two different domains, Sometime the same code works properly but sometimes it is throwing this error :

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy Response to preflight request does'nt pass access control check : No Access Control Allow Origin header is present on the requested resource`

> Cors Middleware :

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CORS
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

> Kernel.php

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        //\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        //'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
        //'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
    ];
}
```

> api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api'],'prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('/refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
    Route::get('/user-profile', [AuthController::class, 'userProfile']);    
});
```

> cors.php

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

> Route Service Provider :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * The controller namespace for the application.
     *
     * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
}
```

Any solution is highly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to your defined Cors middleware,
another Cors middleware has registered in the **Global Middlewares** :
`\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class`

```php
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
/* comment this out*/
 //       \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

you have forgotten the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header for your customized Cors.

```
        $response
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin')
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST, GET, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer so i don't need any  \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,  this package which i installed? Issue was some time when i run i got cors error

Comment: But now after commenting out   \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class, i'm getting cors error and the error is persistent

Comment: so I guess your customized Cors class is not working

Comment: May be any solution for that because i already installed the package `fruitcake/laravel-cors`

Comment: you have forgotten the allow origin methods, I have updated m answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239317/discussion-between-user3653474-and-abilogos).

Comment: getting same issue : Access to XMLHttpRequest at '127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login' from origin 'localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: can you provide your RouteServiceProvider ?

Comment: Added Route service provider in my question, one point i notice should i remove cors middleware from api route, is my kernel.php correct i have updated that file also, please check

Comment: is cors.php has any use or my custom middleware is working

Comment: you can check it [here](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/blob/master/src/HandleCors.php) yours ok, but one from the library can be extendible and can be configured with config files

Comment: but i'm not using this fruitcacke middleware i have called custom one, removing cors middlware from api route now it is working

Comment: so you are done, congrats. your problem has resolved. but for security reason just limit the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your front-end **domain**.

Comment: Thanks for the help do i need to do any other stuff related to cors setting in other places or now this application will run properly on server also

Comment: just be aware to use the cors middle ware on any api end point which is not `GET` & set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your front-end domain.

Comment: This question and solution confirmed works for Laravel 9 (which already have cors middleware but it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

There is another common mistake wich sanctum, after checking all the cnfigurations, make sure your routes are grouped to use the sanctum middleware

as in

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
Route::get('/', function () {
    // Uses sanctum middleware...
});
```