# Local Angular App is showing laravel api response as CORS error when we use functions like print_r(). dd() for debugging in laravel PHP?

Tags: php, angular, laravel, cors, single-page-application

I am struggling with weird problem that I can't use debugging functions when I use print_r() or dd() or echo inside laravel api. API response is always CORS error in this case.

Please note my laravel version is 9

api.php has following route

```
Route::post('create-test-data', 'TestController@createTestData');
```

TestController has following function

```
 public function createTestData(Request $request) { //
        try {

            $data = $request->all();
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($data);exit; 
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
  }
```

Though I have tried different approaches to solve the problem which are

1. Tried defining my own helpers functions with another name similar to mentioned

https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/issues/301

This approach works but problem is if we try multiple dd (custom function as defined) then error come headers already sent because we are defining headers multiple times because of helper function.

2. Also tried creating a new custom middleware named CORS and commenting laravel default CORS middleware which is here in kernel file (this way does not work for me)

> protected $middleware = [
> \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
> ....
> ];

[Getting Cors error in Laravel on some system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005525/getting-cors-error-in-laravel-on-some-system)

But is there any better way to handle this issue with Single Page Applications like using with Angular or React without defining a custom middleware or custom helper functions.

Also want to know more why these simple functions give cors errors when used in api ?

Please Note my laravel apis are from server which is secure using https
Also let me know if there is some sort of setting that needs to be done on server? is this issue server related or just laravel problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the code involved, such that others can check it for problems

Comment: @NicoHaase added more information to question api.php has post route with url and has a function defined in TestController but echo and print_r are giving CORS errors if I want to check which data is coming to api. let me know if you need more info with details